# chat.stackoverflow.com - chat message in inbox

Tags: support, chat

I clicked to join the "endless rant" chat room a little while ago, and ever since I keep getting items in my inbox saying:

> Chat message on Endless rant!
>
> A scheduled chat meeting is starting soon.

I can't seem to figure out how to unsubscribe or prevent this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regular case, just go to [the event page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/565/tech-rant?tab=schedule) (where you registered for the event) and click "cancel your registration".

But since this particular event doesn't make any sense (with the room being frozen), I'll just delete it.